# Multiple json data to jmeter request

Tags: jmeter

I have around 6 json request data, How can i send to jmeter to use all 6 request data for different threads.

In Body data I can put only only one json data.

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You can use a CSV file containing all 6 values to do this, Google JMeter Parametrization

Comment: I tried i could not find the solution.because the json is big string. people gave only small parameterization not with json values.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your 6 JSON values into separate files like:

   - d:\1.json
   - d:\2.json
   - etc.
2. Use combination of

   - [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval)
   - [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum)
   - [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)

functions in order to get data loaded like

```
${__FileToString(${__eval(d:\\${__threadNum}.json)},,)}
```

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) posts series to learn more about different JMeter functions and what can be done with their help.